# how to call a javascript function defined in an object

Tags: javascript, function, function-calls

I have been put on a project where a page, called via a webview, interact with the native application via javascript (this is the first time for me ).

on the page I have some functions that the applciation has to call during execution, but i would like to call them "outside" the application for testing purposes.

the function is defined in this way:

```
window.WEBAPP.callbacks = {
    INTFunction: function(nameData, valueData) {    //doing stuff ... }
}
```

i would like to call the `INTFunction` from "outside" `WEBAPP` wich is the container the native app put around the page.

is it possible to do something like : `window.WEBAPP.callbacks.INTFunction("test","12345");`
or i'm totally wrong and out of way?

Comment: Have you tried and that ? What did you get ?

Comment: Have you tried it? That should work fine...

Comment: actually i get : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'INTFunction' of undefined

Comment: most definitely a subtle spelling problem. should work.

Comment: @peorthyr Are you calling it before the function is defined?

Comment: what does window.WEBAPP give on the console?

Comment: timing and early calling could be the problem... all these script are injected at "some time" and i have little windows to inject my code to make tests, maybe inserting my code after everything should be a way.
all the code of the page is made by injecting it with template features and that complicate all the scenario...

Comment: ok, solved, i must define first what WEBAPP is by adding the test declaration: var WEBAPP = {} ; with this, there are no errors, now i can see if the function is called or not, i'll try.